# VS 2008 Team system files opened in standard 2008

Tags: visual-studio

VS 2008 Team system files opened in standard 2008

If I create a project in VS 2008 team system. And then a colleague opens the project in standard VS 2008 will the project open normally for them? Will they get standard features and see the complete project?

If that works, what other gotchas may occur when using different version of VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can open a project created in Team System in Standard Visual Studio as long as it doesn't utilise the Team System features (i.e. team system foundation server, anything 3rd party requisites)

You can find the features of Team System [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/products/bb980920.aspx) and a comparison between Standard and Professional versions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/products/bb980920.aspx) (which may or not help)

Comment: I am wondering if data gets lost.
If someone opens a team system project in std edition and then changes some code. Then the first person with team system opens project again can they still use the team system features without interuption?

Comment: I use standard edition at home on my home computer (bought it before I joined my current company) and can successfully switch between the two with simple projects that aren't using anything I haven't included. Team System wasn't introduced to be a barrier or to put anything else in place, it was integrated to allow teams better use of the software - i.e. easier integration and collaboration with team-mates, and integration with the Office shell (Excel features)